# one /t creating two tabs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing Zed Shaw's "Learning Ruby the Hard Way," exercise 24, and have come across a problem. There is a point where he has us type this:

```
poem = <<END
\tThe lovely world
with logic so firmly planted
cannot discern \n the needs of love
nor comprehend the passion from intuition
and requires an explanation
\n\t\twhere there is none.
END

puts "-------------"
puts poem
puts "-------------"
```

and somehow my code is doing this:

```
-------------
        The lovely world
with logic so firmly planted
cannot discern
 the needs of love
nor comprehend the passion from intuition
and requires an explanation

                where there is none.
--------------
```

-My 'lovely' line tabbed twice. I also think my line "where there is none." might be over too far as well...

I've checked for an extra space somewhere. after "`<<END`" and after the first and second "`-----`." I've undone the tab to see if it would tab w/o it but it doesn't. I had it on the same line as `<<END` with an `\n\t`, just to see if that would work but I got an error message. Anyone have an idea what's going on? and how to fix it??

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and here is my screen shot [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMrEC.png)
Hopefully this helps you (and me).
I just realised I haven't shown what he says it's supposed to look like so here's that. [screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l5yB.png)

Comment: May be we need more information about your environments.
Your OS (Windows 7, windows 10, ubuntu 14.04, etc.)?
Your terminal name (windows cmd, windows ConEmu, etc.)?
Can you send screenshot of issue?
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be just your terminal outputs tabs quite widely, as 8 spaces. Try something simpler to see the tab width, like this:

```
puts "tab\twidth"
puts "tab........width"
```

You can change tab width in your terminal by (for example to 4 spaces)

```
tabs 4
```

You can also look into man page or settings of your terminal.

Comment: Well, your output here doesn't tell me anything, you need to look into your monitor and count width of a single tab in spaces. Dots are just for your convenience, so it's easier to count.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said and the two lined up. I counted 5 spaces to the 8 dots. So now what?

Comment: Yes, 8 spaces is the standard width of a tab, so the output that the OP got looks fine.  (Although somehow those tabs were converted to spaces on their way from the terminal to the StackOverflow question.)